# Generalising an answer to number of edges on a decision tree

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a general answer to the question, *"How many edges ($e = |E|$) are there for a decision forest (random forest) $G=(V,E)$, when $|V| = n$ and the number of source nodes is equal to $s$, where $n$ includes the number of source nodes"*?

I'm guessing it's something like:

$$e = n-s$$

Which makes sence, as each node has one incoming edge, minus the source node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct, and follows directly from the fundamental properties of trees. In fact, one of the definitions of a tree is that it is

> A connected graph on $n$ nodes with $n-1$ edges.

Therefore, if you have $s$ trees in your forest (and they are pairwise disconnected), and the $i$-th tree has $n_i$ nodes, you know that the $i$-th tree also has $n_i-1$ edges. Alltogether, you therefore have

$$(n_1-1)+(n_2-1)+\cdots+(n_s - 1)$$ edges, and the above simply reorders into $$n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_s - 1 - 1 -\cdots - 1 = n-s$$

because we know $n_1+\cdots+n_s=n$ (the total number of nodes is the sum of the number of nodes in each tree).

It's written even more simply with summation notation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^s (n_i-1) = \sum_{i=1}^sn_i - \sum_{i=1}^s 1 = n - s.$$

Comment: Thank you, exactly the answer I was looking for